# Replace parent path in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

I'm trying to replace the parent directory of a given path

`src/path/to/file.ext` => `dest/path/to/file.newext`

My current solution involves using `string.split`, and looks pretty awful. It works, though.

```
var path = require('path');

var outDir = 'dest/'
var inFile = 'src/path/to/file.ext'
var outFile = path.basename(inFile, path.extname(inFile)) + '.newext';

var destDir = path.join(outDir, path.dirname(inFile.split('/').slice(1).join('/')));
outFile = path.join(destDir, outFile) // dest/path/to/file.newext
```

Is there another way I could go about this?

Comment: That's a completely different question. :) I am trying to replace the beginning part of the path more elegantly `src/file => dest/file` instead of using split like in the code I provided above.

Comment: It's actually the same question, just asked in reverse.  You want to take the path off of a filename.  The question I linked tells you how to take the filename off of the path.  Just add your new path to that filename, and you're good to go.